# NotificationController not found you need to call Get.put or Get.lazyPut

Tags: android, flutter

This error is thrown when I am try to create Notification Page for a navigation bar.
I'm not sure, but seems that it shouldn't be happening. My doubt is about where I'm placing the lazyPut. I don't know if i'm on the right part or not.

[image]

This is the code:

```
import '../../../../common/ui.dart';
import '../../../models/notification_model.dart';
import '../../../repositories/notification_repository.dart';
import '../../root/controllers/root_controller.dart';

class NotificationsController extends GetxController {
  final notifications = <Notification>[].obs;
  NotificationRepository _notificationRepository;

  NotificationsController() {
    _notificationRepository = new NotificationRepository();
  }

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    await refreshNotifications();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future refreshNotifications({bool showMessage}) async {
    await getNotifications();
    Get.find<RootController>().getNotificationsCount();
    if (showMessage == true) {
      Get.showSnackbar(Ui.SuccessSnackBar(
          message: "List of notifications refreshed successfully".tr));
    }
  }

  Future getNotifications() async {
    try {
      notifications.assignAll(await _notificationRepository.getAll());
    } catch (e) {
      Get.showSnackbar(Ui.ErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }

  Future removeNotification(Notification notification) async {
    try {
      _notificationRepository.remove(notification).then((value) {
        if (!notification.read) {
          --Get.find<RootController>().notificationsCount.value;
        }
        notifications.remove(notification);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      Get.showSnackbar(Ui.ErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }

  Future markAsReadNotification(Notification notification) async {
    try {
      _notificationRepository.markAsRead(notification).then((value) {
        if (!notification.read) {
          notification.read = true;
          --Get.find<RootController>().notificationsCount.value;
        }
        notifications.refresh();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      Get.showSnackbar(Ui.ErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

Please How do I remove this error

Answer (score 1):

the answer in the error message you have to call `Get.put(NotificationsController());` in the screen that uses NotificationsController

or add it to GetBuilder builder like this

```
GetBuilder<NotificationsController>(
    init: NotificationsController(),
)
```